# Package org.pdfbox.pdfparser does not exist

Tags: pdfbox

There is following portion in my code:

```
import org.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument; 
import org.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentInformation;
import org.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;
```

When I try to compile, it saws following error:

> package org.pdfbox.pdfparser does not exist.

I have installed the default JDK on Ubuntu so how do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

This is not part of the default JDK installation. You need to get hold of the jar file that contains this code and then add it to your compile-time class path.

so, if you were to download the jar file to /tmp/pdfbox.jar, you'd compile it with

```
javac -cp .:/tmp/pdfbox.jar MyProgram.java
```

PS - downloading it to /tmp isn't a great idea, but you get the picture ......

Comment: Then `java -cp .:/tmp/pdfbox.jar MyProgram`.

Comment: In Windows use `;` instead of `:`.

Answer (score 1):

you must build path it into your lib folder

go to your package explorer and right click on jar file and after that use build path